# How would I return a respondent's responses after survey completion?

Tags: surveymonkey

I fairly new to using the SurveyMonkey API.

My site is designed in WordPress. After users login, they have access to a survey page where there are links to several types of surveys. What I would like to do, after a given survey is completed by a user, is retrieve their responses.

Any ideas on where to begin?

Comment: So you want to poll for when a survey is completed?  I would check out the SurveyMonkey polling guide to get started: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/polling

Comment: My apologies for the lack of clarity. I want the individual user's responses after they have completed the survey. It there a way to retrieve a specific user's ID?

Comment: Weblink respondents are anonymous, unless you use the 'c' query string parameter to identify them.  Email respondents can be identified by their email address.  Both identifiers can be retrieved using get_respondent_list (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list) - you can then use the respondent id associated with that response to retrieve the specific response using get_responses (https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses)

Comment: Awesome, I think that answers my question. The 'c' query will allow me to identify an anonymous survey respondent. I can then use that result to query using the get_responses method.

Comment: @MilesCederman-Haysom: please post your comment as an answer so others can find it.  (The ?c=xxx query string is an important tool in SurveyMonkey.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblink respondents are anonymous, unless you use the 'c' query string parameter to identify them.

Email respondents can be identified by their email address.

Both identifiers can be retrieved using [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list) - you can then use the respondent id associated with that response to retrieve the specific response using [get_responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses).

Note that identifying people using the 'c' parameter appears to be deprecated now - it is no longer listed on the SurveyMonkey help center.  It still technically works, but is not recommended for new development.  The supported way to do this is via [custom varilables](http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/What-are-custom-variables-and-how-do-I-use-them) which requires a platinum account.  You then have unlimited variables to track users, and these are returned in the [get_responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_responses) response.