# Send surveymonkey web links via sms, enable respondent tracking

Tags: surveymonkey

We're trying to put together a survey solution which allows us to send links to our surveys to users via SMS.  I know we could simply take the surveymonkey survey url and send it, but we want the same unique respondent tracking that you get via email, so we can break down responses by respondent group. So to achieve that, every respondent would need a custom, trackable url for each survey.

I see that when you send the survey via email, you get a unique link along the lines of https://www.surveymonkey.com/s.aspx?sm=cun03M8_2br9IdNcpt0CqL9A_3d_3d

I also see in the api documentation for `get_respondent_list` that there's a field "recipient_id" which is described as "ID generated for recipients of survey invitations via email collectors".  It's not obvious from the unique email link if the link includes the survey id and the recipient id, or if it's just a "tracking code" which gets converted to an id later. So I'm just wondering if there's a way to programmatically generate the unique link for a given respondent?

Comment: This has been answered a number of times before.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718508/how-would-i-return-a-respondents-responses-after-survey-completion/26811595#26811595 as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the tracking via the email collector because those must be sent via email from the Survey Monkey system. Additionally, the `recipient_id` that you mention is actually just an internal Survey Monkey id, and not relevant to tracking. A respondent who does two surveys would have two respondent ids.

In your case, I would use many weblink collectors, one for each survey respondent.

**For each survey:**

1. Using the API, [create a survey](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/create_flow) with no collector.

**For each respondent:**

2. Create one [weblink collector](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/create_collector). At this point, it's anonymous.
3. Pass the weblink through a URL shortening API. For example, the [bit.ly API](http://dev.bitly.com/links.html#v3_shorten) can provide the (optional) svy.mk domain.
4. The bit.ly API also allows you to [track metrics](http://dev.bitly.com/link_metrics.html), so you can see who has clicked the survey link. Then you can map those to the response from the Survey Monkey API.
5. Repeat (with code, of course) for each respondent.

Answer (score -1):

Also check out SurveySignal (www.surveysignal.com) that simplifies this capability with existing integration with Survey Monkey